# g++ integer to to string assignment without an error/warning

Tags: gcc, g++, gcc-warning

The following code compiles without any warning or error on G++ (GCC) 4.1.2.

Is there a reason for not issuing an error/warning?

Is there a flag that can cause it to issue a warning or error?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(string &s)
{
    unsigned long u = 123;
   s = u;
}

int main()
{
   string s;

   func (s);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason there's no warning or error is because this is valid C++.  `std::string` overloads the assignment operator (`operator=`) to take a `char`.  `long` can be implicitly converted to a `char`, hence the code makes sense.